# Build fails on Team Services

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops

I have a .NET Azure solution in Visual Studio 2015. The application uses 2 worker roles.

As part of it's functionality, at some point in the build process a couple of dlls are copied in to the cloud project so they end up in the end result.

To make it work I've added the following in "ServiceDefinition.csdef":

```
<WorkerRole name="SomeProject.Foreman" vmsize="Small">
  <Contents>
    <Content destination="ClientCustomCode">
      <SourceDirectory path="ClientCustomCode" />
    </Content>
  </Contents>
  <ConfigurationSettings>
    <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
    <Setting name="SomeProjectDocumentDBURI" />
    <Setting name="SomeProjectAuthorizationKey" />
    <Setting name="LogLevel" />
    <Setting name="RequestQueue" />
    <Setting name="RequestErrorQueue" />
    <Setting name="NumberOfConcurrentRequests" />
    <Setting name="NumberOfRequestsToReadFromAzureQueue" />
    <Setting name="StorageConnectionString" />
    <Setting name="SomeProjectPnrHistory" />
    <Setting name="SomeProjectClientRepository" />
    <Setting name="SomeProjectMessagesInProcess" />
  </ConfigurationSettings>
  <LocalResources>
    <LocalStorage name="InstallLogs" sizeInMB="5" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
  </LocalResources>
  <Startup>
    <Task commandLine="install.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
      <Environment>
        <Variable name="PathToInstallLogs">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='InstallLogs']/@path" />
        </Variable>
      </Environment>
    </Task>
  </Startup>
</WorkerRole>

<WorkerRole name="SomeProject.Engine" vmsize="Small">
  <Contents>
    <Content destination="ClientCustomCode">
      <SourceDirectory path="ClientCustomCode" />
    </Content>
  </Contents>
  <ConfigurationSettings>
    <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
    <Setting name="RequestQueue" />
    <Setting name="RequestErrorQueue" />
    <Setting name="SomeProjectDocumentDBURI" />
    <Setting name="SomeProjectAuthorizationKey" />
    <Setting name="LogLevel" />
    <Setting name="NumberOfConcurrentRequests" />
    <Setting name="NumberOfRequestsToReadFromAzureQueue" />
    <Setting name="StorageConnectionString" />
    <Setting name="SomeProjectPnrHistory" />
    <Setting name="SomeProjectClientRepository" />
    <Setting name="SomeProjectMessagesInProcess" />
  </ConfigurationSettings>
  <LocalResources>
    <LocalStorage name="InstallLogs" sizeInMB="5" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
  </LocalResources>
  <Startup>
    <Task commandLine="install.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
      <Environment>
        <Variable name="PathToInstallLogs">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/LocalResources/LocalResource[@name='InstallLogs']/@path" />
        </Variable>
      </Environment>
    </Task>
  </Startup>
</WorkerRole>
```

In the cloud project I added the following in the build events:

```
-- Pre-build
IF NOT EXIST $(TargetDir)ClientCustSomCode mkdir $(TargetDir)ClientCustomCode

-- Post-build
IF NOT EXIST $(TargetDir)ClientCustomCode mkdir $(TargetDir)ClientCustomCode
copy $(ProjectDir)ClientCustomCode\*.dll $(TargetDir)ClientCustomCode
copy $(ProjectDir)ClientCustomCode\*.pdb $(TargetDir)ClientCustomCode
```

In the project file where the copied dll is actually build:

```
copy $(TargetName).dll $(SolutionDir)SomeProject\SomeProject.Cloud\ClientCustomCode
copy $(TargetName).pdb $(SolutionDir)SomeProject\SomeProject.Cloud\ClientCustomCode
```

Now, locally this builds with no problem. Until recently it also build on Team Services, but out of the blue, without any real reason (nothing was changed) the build suddenly started to fail with the following error:

```
2016-08-23T08:37:40.3013767Z   C:\a\1\s\SomeStuff\SomeProject\SomeProject.Cloud\ServiceDefinition.csdef : error CloudServices089: Cannot find the source directory 'C:\a\1\s\SomeStuff\SomeProject\SomeProject.Cloud\ClientCustomCode' in role SomeProject.Foreman. [C:\a\1\s\SomeStuff\SomeProject\SomeProject.Cloud\SomeProject.Cloud.ccproj]
2016-08-23T08:37:40.3013767Z   C:\a\1\s\SomeStuff\SomeProject\SomeProject.Cloud\ServiceDefinition.csdef : error CloudServices089: Cannot find the source directory 'C:\a\1\s\SomeStuff\SomeProject\SomeProject.Cloud\ClientCustomCode' in role SomeProject.Engine. [C:\a\1\s\SomeStuff\SomeProject\SomeProject.Cloud\SomeProject.Cloud.ccproj]
```

**Build log file:** [Download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54991757/StackOverflow/Buildlog.txt) 
Does anyone here might have an idea?

Comment: Can you share the entire build logs?

Comment: I'll add it to my question. :-)

Comment: I've included the build log

Answer (score 0):

> error CloudServices089: Cannot find the source directory 'C:\a\1\s\SomeStuff\SomeProject\SomeProject.Cloud\ClientCustomCode' in role SomeProject.Foreman. [C:\a\1\s\SomeStuff\SomeProject\SomeProject.Cloud\SomeProject.Cloud.ccproj]

The install.cmd is used to create directory and copy assemblies to the new directory. From the error message, I think the install.cmd is not executed. Maybe the install.cmd does not deploy to worker role. Please verify via enable Remote desktop when publish the application:
[image]
We could find the install.cmd in the directory `E:\approot` in worker role instance.

Please try to find install.cmd in your solution, then set the Copy to Output Directory as Copy always to see whether it works, like following:

[image]

Comment: Deployment still works, it's only the automated build on Team Services that fails.